# Expandable block - retain scroll position after closing

Tags: javascript, html, css

We have a page with several expandable blocks - some nested.  Each block has a close icon on the header and footer.

[image]

When closing the icon by the footer close button the page content scrolls up to fill the space - leaving the user in a confusing  page location further down the page - ideally the page would close to display the header of the closed element.  What is the cleanest technical solution to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: `element.scrollIntoView` your top/bottom element? Perhaps with `behaviour: 'smooth'` and some other settings like centering the block?